# jlink not finding module-info.class

Tags: java, maven-3, jlink

I am using a maven project with the layout

```
src
  main
    java
      <some-package-name>
       module-info.java
```

The only plugin I am using is the maven-compiler-plugin, version 3.7.0.

```
 <build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>9</source>
                <target>9</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
     </plugins>
  </build>
```

when i run the command  `jlink --module-path $JAVA_HOME/jmods:target --add-modules foo --output jre` 
the output is `Error: Two versions of module foo found in target (foo.jar and classes)`

However when I run `jlink --module-path $JAVA_HOME/jmods:target/foo.jar --add-modules foo --output jre` it says `Error: Module foo not found`

So jlink is able to see the module exists, but cannot find my module-info.  Is there something I am missing with maven to get that file in the right place?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on how Maven deals with java modules, so I can't provide a full answer. But I don't see the module folder "foo" in your diagram, and that would make it difficult to locate foo's module-info.class. A proper module requires *both* a file folder named your-module-name, and a module-info with the contents "module your-module-name{...}"

```
src
   main
      java
         foo
            module-info.class
            the-compiled-java-classes-of-your-application
```

Something like the above structure should be a step in the right direction.

This assumes your module-info.class is "module foo{...}"